# How to get the SHA1 hash of a file into a string var using AutoHotkey?

Tags: hash, firefox-addon, sha1, autohotkey

Salvete!  How can I use autohotkey to get the SHA1 hash of a file into a string variable?  I know how to use the Crypt.ahk library to get the SHA1 hash of a string into a string var, but how do I get it for a file?

Background: I am using autohotkey to automate the process of building a firefox addon.  I need the sha1 hash of the final xpi file so I can add it to the update.rdf file.

I found [this thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=23584) in the autohotkey forums, but it is very old, and the download link to their solution is dead.

The solution doesn't have to be purely autohokey - but it *does* have to involve a way or method to achieve the result with autohokey as the instigator; in other words, if autohotkey could access some dll or commandline application and fetch the resulting string into a variable, that would be mighty nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha!  Got it!

The AutoHotkey Forum finally came through - a kind fellow pointed me to the link.
I compared the results against Nir Sofer's HashMyFiles and got the same results.
This works absolutely perfectly.
Autohotkey can do *anything*.  And so I conclude that it is not such a bad choice for packaging firefox addons!

http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=64211

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nsiCryptoHash interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICryptoHash)

Comment: Interesting. Do you by chance have a simple example of how to use it with autohotkey?

Comment: I didn't notice that you asked a way to get the SHA1 hash from autohotkey. It doesn't look the right tool for extension packaging.

Comment: The question was tagged *autohotkey*, you know.  I chose autohotkey will do almost anything, and it will also publish the extension to my website.  In fact, my autohotkey script will do everything I want except get the hash, which is the reason I posted this.